# Importing csv as dictionary - none type error

Tags: python, dictionary

How can I import a .csv file as a dictionary?

I'm trying to import a .csv file as a dictionary. The .csv file has two columns: a key called "AIRPORT CODE" and an element called "AIRPORT". I first try to import it as a list because I figured its easier to convert from a list to a dictionary.

```
def load_airports_dict(filename):
    import csv

    reader = csv.reader(open(filename, 'r'))
    data_list = []

    for row in reader:
        data_list.append(row)

    d = { }

    for row in data_list:
        d[row[0]] = row[1]
    print(d)
```

Unfortunately, when trying to call a function to slice the dictionary I get ''NoneType' object is not subscriptable' even though if I run the code outside of the function it gives me what I'm looking for.

Comment: Please show the full traceback

Comment: Your function doesn't have a `return` statement.

Answer (score 2):

1. Don't import things in definitions
2. Use `with`
3. You need a `return` statement.

With all that:

```
import csv
def load_airports_dict(filename):
    result = {}
    with open(filename, 'r') as handle:
        reader = csv.reader(handle)
        for row in reader:
            result[row[0]] = row[1]
    return result
```

Comment: That's a long shot if ever I saw one.